# what if I've asked a question, but after a while realized that problem was in something else, what should I do?

Tags: support, questions

Regarding the situation described in title, what should I do with my question, close it, delete it, what? What should be done in case someone already posted an answer/comment? What should be done, if none posted nothing?

Comment: Think ,Refer and  Try well before you ask :-)

Answer (score 0):

Well, it depends.

- If there is still some relation between the new problem and the previous problem try to edit the question keeping the original and explaining what was changed, assuming it won't render any given answers meaningless. That's the best option.
- If the question is not salvageable:

  1. In case of no answers, just delete it. You have delete link and binding vote.
  2. In case of answers but none upvoted you can still delete your question, but think twice if you can't salvage the question as explained above.
  3. In case of upvoted answers you can't delete your question anymore; edit it to explain what happened and comment on the answers if you want.